# Progress indicator for git clone

Tags: git, progress, git-clone

Is it possible to get a progress bar when doing a `git clone`? I'm wondering because I am currently doing a git clone that has taken a few minutes so far and would be curious to know if it is going to finish soon.

Comment: Git 2.10 should be more talkative with `git clone --progress`: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38783446/6309)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I am currently doing a git clone that has taken a few minutes so far and would be curious to know if it is going to finish soon.

With Git 2.10 (Q3 2016), `git clone --progress` will be more verbose.

See [commit 38e590e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38e590ea12336bcfae0310092885743e6ba79781) by Jeff King (`peff`)
<sup>(Merged by Junio C Hamano in [commit a58a8e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a58a8e3f7156dadd5d5e9643168545ff057c111a) Aug. 4th 2016)</sup>

> ### `clone`: use a real progress meter for connectivity check
>
> Because the initial connectivity check for a cloned
>   repository can be slow, [0781aa4 (`clone`: let the user know
>   when `check_everything_connected` is run, 2013-05-03)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0781aa4766ed88d620ea060c7d775ca806ebfa93) added a
>   "fake" progress meter; we simply say "`Checking connectivity`"
>   when it starts, and "`done`" at the end, with nothing between.
>
> Since `check_connected()` now knows how to do a real progress
>   meter, we can drop our fake one and use that one instead.

As noted by [ks1322](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72178/ks1322) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640020/progress-indicator-for-git-clone/38783446#comment108420342_38783446)

> `--progress` is enabled by default when you run `git clone` from a terminal.  There is no need to write it explicitly for terminal.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 But the --progress is there, isn't it? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---progress) Even though, yes, it is not in the synopsis.

Comment: `--progress` is enabled by default when you run `git clone` from a terminal. There is no need to write it explicitly for terminal.

Comment: @ks1322 Good point, thank you. I have inclduded your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I couldn't understand why my CI scripts did't tell me what Git was doing whereas the same commands on my terminal did. Now I know and am glad to know `--progress`.

Answer (score 24):

Not really. There are various stages to `git clone`:

1. discover the objects that need to be sent ("Counting objects: nnn")
2. compress and send those objects
3. index the received pack
4. check out received files

Stage 1 involves walking through the commit graph from each branch head finding all the commits and associated objects: since there is no idea beforehand of how many commits there are, the progress of this can't be gauged. Sadly this is often where a lot of the time in a clone operation is taken up.

Stage 2 does have a progress counter, although it counts objects rather than volume (so its rate varies, especially if the repo has large blobs)

Stages 3 and 4 have progress counters, although they are usually much faster than the previous two stages.

Answer (score 17):

You can do:

```
   du -s .git
```

to monitor changes in the size of temporary content to get an idea.

```
   watch du -s .git
```

allows you to monitor without having to retype the command. Something like the one-liner below will give periodically you the data accumulation rate in kB per second:

```
    delay=5; prev=`du -sk .git/ | cut -f 1`; sleep $delay; while true; do  cur=`du -sk  .git/ | cut -f 1`; expr \( $cur - $prev \) / $delay ; prev=$cur; sleep $delay; done
```

Answer (score 5):

This may not be the direct answer to the question precisely. In my case, when I'm trying to get the progress of `git-lfs clone` a large-language-model, which might take quite a while, I just get into the cloning directory and do `watch du -ksh` if you're on Linux

Comment: yeah that works, however still unknown about which file is currently downloading in case of multiple large files in repo.

Comment: For Mac OS X, we could use `while :; do clear; du -ksh; sleep 2; done`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the folder

```
$project/.git/objects/pack
```

While cloning, there should be a file starting with `tmp_pack_`. It contains the currently downloading git pack.

With this information you might be able to eyeball the duration.

Answer (score 1):

How about `git clone --progress` ?

Comment: `--progress` is enabled by default when you run it from a terminal

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Not inside a Dockerfile apparently. Thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install Git LFS:

```
git lfs install
```

Clone the repository:

```
git lfs clone <repository>
```