# How to show progress for submodule fetching?

Tags: git

I know I can tell Git to show progress like

```
Resolving deltas:  98% (123/125)
```

when passing the command line parameter `--progress` to, e.g. the fetch command. But we have a couple of large submodules and there no progress is shown. How to tell Git to also show progress for cloning submodules (e.g. as part of the fetch command)?

Comment: related for clone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640020/progress-indicator-for-git-clone

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Starting with Git v2.11.0, the `git submodule` interface accepts the `--progress` option which you can use. It does exactly what you expect.

See: https://github.com/git/git/commit/72c5f88311dab7149fcca1f6029414ccb776fee8

`--progress` wasn't announced in the help text (`git submodule --help`) in earlier versions but now it is (tested with Git version 2.27.0)

Answer (score 2):

The closest I came was to use this command:

```
git fetch --recurse-submodules=yes --jobs=10
```

This is not giving you a progress bar. But it speeds up the fetching of the repositories. This helped me a whole lot on a microservice project with ~30 submodules.

Of course, you can combine this with other commands afterwards, for example, update all repositories without potential conflicts:

```
# run all subprojects updates: Pull on currently selected branches

#git submodule foreach 'git rebase origin/master; true'
git submodule foreach '
  export BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  git status -bs
  if [[ "master" == $BRANCH_NAME ]]
  then
    git merge FETCH_HEAD --ff-only
  else
    echo \"NOTE this branch is $BRANCH_NAME. You must merge/rebase yourself!\"
  fi
'
```