# git clone and git lfs pull doesn't pull the LFS files at all

Tags: git, git-pull, git-lfs

I'm cloned a repository via SSH and it seemed to clone everything without an issue. Then I moved into the respective folder and then did `git lfs pull`. However, this is greeted with no objects being downloaded. I've done LFS pulls before, and objects have downloaded so I know what to expect as a progress message or output. But this `git lfs pull` gives me nothing.

A full list of commands of what needs to be done according to most tutorials:

```
git lfs install
git clone --recurse-submodules git@gitlab_host_website.company.net:project_name.git
cd project_folder
git lfs pull
```

When I try to run `git lfs ls-files`, I notice that the LFS files have been cloned into my local repository. How can I resolve this to get the LFS files from the remote repo?

My suspicion is that since I have a Developer role on the repo, it is somehow hindering this LFS pull. Everyone else on my team who is able to do the LFS pull has either Maintainer or Owner role/permissions. Before they move forward with changing my access I wanted to try different solutions to see if anything works.

**What I've already tried (and doesn't work):**

- I've have tried setting `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE flag = 1` when cloning and pulling and also `git lfs install --skip-smudge`. In another iteration, I also tried `git lfs install --force` to no avail.
- `git status` shows a clean working tree
- `git lfs fetch` with `-C folder_name` and `--all` flags finds ~200 objects and fetches all references. That's all.
- `git lfs pull -I "path\to\folder"` also gives me nothing like in the original case.
- `git remote add origin git@gitlab_host_website.company.net:project_name.git` -- Doing this didn't help with the git lfs pull
- `git lfs track` shows me nothing when I specify some LFS files present in the remote repo (and as you may have guessed, doesn't exist on my local system)
- `git reset` didn't help either but it wasn't really needed.
- `git config lfs.url $(git config remote.origin.url)` followed by `git config lfs.url` does not work in helping me pull the LFS files.
- `git checkout -fB main origin/main` once again not needed but worth a shot.
- `git config --global http.sslVerify true` followed by git config --global http.sslBackend schannel` was also a bust. LFS pull didn't work after this either.

Comment: Did you try this? `git config --global --add safe.directory <your_repo_path>`

Comment: Yes I tried it but to no avail :( It's for this one specific repo that this happens so I'm stumped. Even IT is confused.

Comment: Did you try enabling git trace output?
As described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460811/git-submodule-update-is-slow-how-can-i-debug-why-its-slow/71558167#71558167