# Git clone doesn't show progress

Tags: windows, git, cmd, progress

I'm trying to get the progress of git clone without success.

I tried with `git clone --progress <path> 2>stderr.txt` but it only returns:

```
Cloning into 'project-name'...
done.
```

The output that I need would be something like:

```
Progress: 1/100
Progress: 2/100
Progress: 3/100
```

My git version is 2.21.0.windows.1

Edit:

I'm calling `git clone` from NodeJS using `child_process` with the following code:

```js
let cloneSpawn = spawn("git", ["clone", "--progress", path], {shell: true});
cloneSpawn.stderr.on("data", d => {
  console.log(d.toString());
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress indicator for git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640020/progress-indicator-for-git-clone)

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: @lucas, which answer(s) to [Progress indicator for git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640020/progress-indicator-for-git-clone) did you try, and what problems did you have with it (them)?

Comment: @Preacher Tried with --progress flag. Monitoring folder size isn't an option because the execution blocks the program.

Answer (score 2):

Clone progress is output to stderr.  The `--progress` flag forces it to occur even if stderr is not a tty device (as in, the [C library `isatty()` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) returns false/0).

Unfortunately, `--progress` inside `git clone` works by invoking other Git programs, and it fails to pass the `--progress` flag to *those* programs.  Those programs do their own separate `isatty()` test, which says that your redirected stderr is not a tty, so *those* programs don't print any progress messages.

Fixing this requires fixing the underlying Git bug.  The workaround, should you choose to do that, is to connect your `git clone` to something that satisfies the `isatty` test: a pseudo-tty, on Linux and similar systems.  (I don't know what does the trick on Windows.)

Comment: I'm actually reading the stderr from nodejs. I updated the main post with the code.

Comment: I don't know what that does on Windows. The Unix-ish equivalent is to fork and exec with output directed through a pipe, and pipe objects are not "tty-ish" and hence fail the isatty() test. (About three years ago, I wrote a big Python program to maintain a bunch of repositories, and wanted to have it grab progress indications, and ran into this very same issue.)