# Is there a way to see "pod update" or "git clone" progress in percents?

Tags: git, macos, cocoapods

I'm doing `pod update MyPod --verbose` for my pod, which lives in a private Github repo (so downloaded via ssh). Sometimes in takes 5 minutes, sometimes 25 (thus driving me crazy). I'm using `--verbose` to see what's going on.
Usually it stucks on `git clone`:

```
Fetching external sources
-> Pre-downloading: `MyPod` from `MyGithubUrl`, branch `MyBranch`
  $ /usr/bin/git ls-remote MyGithubUrl MyBranch
  611a1146a741404d6e4a982fa1548c95d3772d54  refs/heads/MyBranch
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone MyBranch
     /var/folders/kj/55ym60x155dctzvc8pvym10r0000gn/T/d20210830-13232-1gq5j6e --template=
     Cloning into '/var/folders/kj/55ym60x155dctzvc8pvym10r0000gn/T/d20210830-13232-1gq5j6e'...
```

I'm checking a `Network` tab in `Activity Monitor` to see if the download is in progress - and yes, it is, but I don't see smth like "pod update is 56% completed":
[image]

Is there a way to see the exact progress of `Git download` step of `pod update`?

Comment: Worth mentioning: the progress numbers from Git tend to count up to *something*, but the *something* may be variable-size units. For instance, during `receiving objects`, Git knows how many objects to expect. Say there are 100 objects. When you've gotten 50 objects, you'll be at 50/100, or 50%. But what if the first 50 objects are *tiny* objects, 100 bytes each, and the *last* 50 objects are huge, 1 MB each? You're at 50% of *objects* but about 1% of *data*.

Comment: The likelihood of things being this skewed is low, but one really-big-object (one DVD video at 4.7 GB) will look like things have gotten stuck, when all the other objects are small.

Comment: @torek Thanks, that's useful! Anyway, if we are considering just the source code repo, there should be no 4 GB video files, and I hope the files are more-or-less uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Progress indicator for git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38783446/6309)", [`--progress`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---progress) is enabled by default when you run `git clone` from a terminal

But that is not the case when run from a script/command like `pod update`.

This is followed by [`CocoaPods/CocoaPods` issue 1349](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1349) which confirms:

> From a quick test adding the [`--progress` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---progress) to the git clone commands is not working.
>
> We have discussed this issue and concluded that progress indicator would be nice to have.
> However implementing it is not trivial per se and taking into account the requirements of an indented verbose output.
> Many other package managers do not display progress for git downloads.
>
> Another point, is that progress indicator would be just a bandaid and the real solution is fast downloads.
> Download speed has greatly been improved in the last releases.
> For those edge cases where the original repo is really huge we recommend to check the “`Activity Monitor`” App.
>
> Closing as won't fix.